# Why does blockTable not work?

Tags: visualforce

Let's say we have page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="Accounts">
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="acc">
    <apex:column value="{!acc.name}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

but I got nothing. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me (with the trailing `</apex:page>` added). You must have Account records in your org for data rows to appear.

Comment: I have got more then 200 records in Account in my org. At least 'select count() from  account' says about it

Comment: @pincet Then quite weird. If you are using a system administrator login, then profile settings should not be involved. One thing that is left to look at is sharing settings.